# Strange behaivor of triangulatePoints() method

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, triangulation

I'm trying to use the triangulatePoints() method from OpenCV to reconstruct 3d objects

I generated projection matrices for two cameras, and they look normal.
But the triangulation method returns the same 3d values for different input 2D coordinates. What can be wrong?

```py
#code
print('Projection matrices:')
print(P0,'\n',P1, '\n')


points = np.array([
    [[381,198],[433,418]],
    [[393,231],[435,453]],
    [[415,225],[465,454]],
    [[406,195],[169,420]]
])


for p in points:
    print('2D coordinates: {}, {}'.format(p[0], p[1]))
    s = np.array(cv2.triangulatePoints(P0, P1, 
                              p[0], 
                              p[1])).T


    print('3D coordinates: {}'.format(s[0][:-1]/np.max(s[0][-1])))
    print()


#Output:
#Projection matrices:
[[587.42947475   0.         223.06652927   0.        ]
 [  0.         587.42947475 236.78123179   0.        ]
 [  0.           0.           1.           0.        ]] 
 [[ 5.87429475e+02  0.00000000e+00  2.23066529e+02 -1.09198390e+04]
 [ 0.00000000e+00  5.87429475e+02  2.36781232e+02  0.00000000e+00]
 [ 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  1.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00]] 

2D coordinates: [381 198], [433 418]
3D coordinates: [-1.00049629  0.          0.        ]

2D coordinates: [393 231], [435 453]
3D coordinates: [-1.00049629  0.          0.        ]

2D coordinates: [415 225], [465 454]
3D coordinates: [-1.00049629  0.          0.        ]

2D coordinates: [406 195], [169 420]
3D coordinates: [-1.00049629  0.          0.        ]
```

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer: It's necessary to specify dtype in image points initialization as np.float32:

```
points = np.array([
    [[381,198],[433,418]],
    [[393,231],[435,453]],
    [[415,225],[465,454]],
    [[406,195],[169,420]]
], dtype=np.float32)
```

After this output is correct:

```
2D coordinates: [381. 198.], [433. 418.]
3D coordinates: [ -76.17712   -33.213867 -265.16254 ]

2D coordinates: [393. 231.], [435. 453.]
3D coordinates: [-110.72584  -66.3086  -358.42117]

2D coordinates: [415. 225.], [465. 454.]
3D coordinates: [-105.021255  -54.279873 -300.12518 ]

2D coordinates: [406. 195.], [169. 420.]
3D coordinates: [14.564291   5.4381375 43.69199  ]
```